# How can I get session in forms?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-sessions

I have a multistep form with checkboxes, after the user submit the first step form I save the objects he checked on his session, at the second step form I would like to filter the objects with the session datas.

To accomplish this I need to get the session on the new ModelForm for the second step, unfortunaltely `request` is not defined in forms.

How can I access my sessions ?

```
class IconSubChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    session_icons = request.session.get('icons')
    query = Q(tags__contains=session_icons[0]) | Q(tags__contains=session_icons[1]) | Q(tags__contains=session_icons[2])
    icons = CustomSubChoiceField(queryset=CanvaIcon.objects.filter(query), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = CanvaIcon
        fields = ['icons']
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Can you share the code. I have the same requirement but when I processthe form using ```form =FormName(request.post)``` it throws exception saying ```Queryset has no attribute session```

Comment: Plus am using the ```request.session['key']=[]``` and ```MultipleChoiceFieldForm```

Comment: can You help me out [with this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57830992/error-while-accessing-request-sessionkey-inside-forms-using-checkboxselect) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have found, you can't access `request` inside the form definition.

You can override the `__init__` method to take extra parameters, and set the queryset for your field. In the example below, I've used `session_icons` as the argument, instead of `request`.

```
class IconSubChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    icons = CustomSubChoiceField(queryset=CanvaIcon.objects.none(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        session_icons = kwargs.pop('session_icons')
        super(IconSubChoiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['icons'].queryset = CanvaIcon.objects.filter(...)
```

Then in your view, instantiate your form with `session_icons`.

```
form = IconSubChoiceForm(data=request.POST, session_icons=request.session.get('icons'))
```

Comment: Alright, I tried it but it is giving me this error `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'queryset'`, CustomSubChoiceField is asking a queryset argument, what should I put in it ?

Comment: You can use the empty queryset `queryset=CanvaIcon.objects.none()`, since you are going to replace it in the `__init__` method.