# Error while accessing request.session['key'] inside forms. [using CheckboxSelectMultiple]

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-request

I have two forms named `GoodAtForm` and `PaidForForm`. What  these do is as follows...

1. `GoodAtForm` Takes an input from a list in `request.session['love']` and presents it to the user.
2. Then user is presented with a `CheckboXSelectMultiple` fields so that users can select.
3. After The form is submitted in the view, the user choices are then stored inside another list `request.session['good']`.

4.Another Form named `PaidForForm` uses that list for further asking of questions from users using `CheckBocSelectMultiple` and the selections are from the list ```request.session['good'].

My problem is that I am unable to access output data inside the Forms to provide it to view.

Input is working fine when initialised. My forms renders Check Boxes from the given LOVE list but the problem is that Form is not providing output. It says

```
 form = GoodAtForm(request.POST)
 input_list = request.session['love']
'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'session'
```

This is my `GoodAtForm`

```
class GoodAtForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GoodAtForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        input_list = request.session['love']
        self.fields['good'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            label="Select Things You are Good At",
            choices=[(c, c) for c in input_list],
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
        )
```

**View For the GoodAtForm**

```
def show_good_at(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = GoodAtForm(request.POST)  #it is showing problem here. Throws an exception here
        if form.is_valid():
            if not request.session.get('good'):
                request.session['good'] = []
            request.session['good'] = form.cleaned_data['good']
            return redirect('paid_for')
    else:
        form = GoodAtForm(request=request)  #rendering form as usual from the list 'love'
        return render(request, 'good_at_form.html', {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the first "positional" argument passed to a Django form is the request data, you've defined `request` as the first argument to your form class but are passing `request.POST` in your view

You either need to pass request as the first argument every time that you instantiate your form

```
form = GoodForm(request, request.POST)
```

or change request to be a keyword argument

```
class GoodAtForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, request=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...

form = GoodForm(request.POST, request=request)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy! I was mixing the two. Code Flowing smooth as water